# $X$= the set of all continuously differentiable functions on $[a,b]$. Show that $d(f,g)$ is a metric.

Tags: proof-verification, derivatives, continuity, metric-spaces

$\displaystyle d(f,g)=\sup_{a\leq x \leq b} |f(x)-g(x)|+ \sup_{a\leq x \leq b} |f'(x)-g'(x)|, \quad f,g \in X$.

Approach:

$|f(x)-g(x)| \leq |f(x)-h(x)|+|h(x)-g(x)| \implies$

$ |f(x)-g(x)| \leq  \displaystyle\sup_{ x\in [a,b]}\bigg[|f(x)-h(x)|+|g(x)-h(x)| \bigg]  \leq \displaystyle\sup_{ x\in [a,b]}|f(x)-h(x)|+ \displaystyle\sup_{ x\in [a,b]}|h(x)-g(x)| \implies$

$\displaystyle\sup_{ x\in [a,b]} |f(x)-g(x)| \leq 
\displaystyle\sup_{ x\in [a,b]}|f(x)-h(x)|+ \displaystyle\sup_{ x\in [a,b]}|h(x)-g(x)|. \quad \quad $ $(1)$ Similarly, the other inequality $(2)$ is obtained and $(1)+(2)$ gives us the required triangle inequality. [Continuity of the derivative ensures that the function is everywhere defined and bounded]

Is this a valid approach? Please verify.

Comment: Remember that you must show that all of the metric axioms hold. Your expansion of the triangle inequality shows that the usual "sup norm" part of the triangle inequality holds, and as you mention, the part for the derivatives is similar. Possibly these should be done together, rather than separately.

Comment: @SamM I am comfortable in this case with the other axioms. I wanted to know whether my procedure is valid or not.

Comment: In which case your argument seems quite reasonable, although as I mentioned I would do both "parts" simultaneously if I were prove this.But that is not to say that your approach is any less (or more) valid.